# How to find all elements on the webpage through scrolling using SeleniumWebdriver and Python

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, lazy-loading, webdriverwait

I can't seem to get all elements on a webpage. No matter what I have tried using selenium. I am sure I am missing something. Here's my code. The url has at least 30 elements yet whenever I scrape only 6 elements return. What am I missing?

```
import requests
import webbrowser
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException



headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://www.adidas.com/us/men-shoes-new_arrivals'

res = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
page_soup = bs(res.text, "html.parser")


containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "gl-product-card-container show-variation-carousel"})


print(len(containers))
#for each container find shoe model
shoe_colors = []

for container in containers:
    if container.find("div", {'class': 'gl-product-card__reviews-number'}) is not None:
        shoe_model = container.div.div.img["title"]
        review = container.find('div', {'class':'gl-product-card__reviews-number'})
        review = int(review.text)



driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
shoe_prices = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.gl-price')

for price in shoe_prices:
    print(price.text)
print(len(shoe_prices))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a selenium question.

Comment: That's exactly what I am using to find elements. I just cant find all the elements in shoe_prices when I run my script for some reason

Comment: you use requests + bs, not selenium though, right?

Comment: Yes but requests + bs couldn't access a span tag which made me import Selenium. I use webdriver.Chrome() help find the shoe price. When I run my for loop for all the elements only 6  prices show. It's supposed to be 30+ prices and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there seems to be some difference in the results as using your *code trial*:

- You find **30** items with **requests** and **6** items with **Selenium**
- Where as I found **40** items with **requests** and **4** items with **Selenium**

This items on this website are dynamically generated through [Lazy Loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) so you have to `scrollDown` and wait for the new elements to render within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import requests
  import webbrowser
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException

  headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}
  url = 'https://www.adidas.com/us/men-shoes-new_arrivals'
  res = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
  page_soup = bs(res.text, "html.parser")
  containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "gl-product-card-container show-variation-carousel"})
  print(len(containers))
  shoe_colors = []
  for container in containers:
      if container.find("div", {'class': 'gl-product-card__reviews-number'}) is not None:
      shoe_model = container.div.div.img["title"]
      review = container.find('div', {'class':'gl-product-card__reviews-number'})
      review = int(review.text)
  options = Options()
  options.add_argument('start-maximized')
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get(url)
  myLength = len(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.gl-price"))))
  while True:
      driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,400)", "")
      try:
          WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver: len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.gl-price")) > myLength)
          titles = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.gl-price")
          myLength = len(titles)
      except TimeoutException:
          break
  print(myLength)
  for title in titles:
      print(title.text)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  47
  $100
  $100
  $100
  $100
  $100
  $100
  $180
  $180
  $180
  $180
  $130
  $180
  $180
  $130
  $180
  $130
  $200
  $180
  $180
  $130
  $60
  $100
  $30
  $65
  $120
  $100
  $85
  $180
  $150
  $130
  $100
  $100
  $80
  $100
  $120
  $180
  $200
  $130
  $130
  $100
  $120
  $120
  $100
  $180
  $90
  $140
  $100
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much. This helps a lot. I wouldnt have any idea how to do scroll down.

Answer (score 1):

you have to slowly scroll down the page. It only request price data with ajax when product viewed.

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = 'https://www.adidas.com/us/men-shoes-new_arrivals'
driver.get(url)

scroll_times = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('col-s-6')) / 4 # (divide by 4 column product per row)
scrolled = 0
scroll_size = 400

while scrolled < scroll_times:
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, arguments[0]);', scroll_size)
    scrolled +=1
    scroll_size += 400
    time.sleep(1)

shoe_prices = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('gl-price')

for price in shoe_prices:
    print(price.text)

print(len(shoe_prices))
```