# Trying to scroll through side-window and extract all HTML elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to print all the 'p6n-ellipsis' elements in an intranet site that I'm working with.  Here is my pseudo-code.

```
page_source = url
html_page = wd.page_source 
soup = bs(html_page, 'html.parser')

scroll_times = len(wd.find_elements_by_class_name('p6n-ellipsis')) 
scrolled = 0
scroll_size = 40

while scrolled < scroll_times:
    wd.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, arguments[0]);', scroll_size)
    scrolled +=1
    scroll_size += 40
    time.sleep(1)

all_tables = wd.find_elements_by_class_name('p6n-ellipsis')
for item in all_tables:
    print(item.text)
```

There seems to be some relationship between what's visible in the side window, and what BS + Selenium can 'see'.  For one thing, the 'scroll_times' variable is always 28, but this number should be over 300.  I want to make it dynamic, by counting the class name of 'p6n-ellipsis' but even if I hard-code this number to 500, or something much higher than 28, I always get 28 items printed out.  I think the code above is close, but something is off, because the scroll window is not moving.  For reference, I'm following the example from the link below.

[How to find all elements on the webpage through scrolling using SeleniumWebdriver and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53680597/how-to-find-all-elements-on-the-webpage-through-scrolling-using-seleniumwebdrive)

I'd really appreciate some assistance with this.  TIA.

Comment: Are all the elements in 1 "document" IE: Are there iframes rendered ?

Comment: I see something called class = 'md-virtual-repeat-container' and id = 'vertical-container'.  I don't see anything called 'iframes'.